# Is there any effect of mehendi (henna) scraps on wuzo (ablution)?

Tags: wudu

After using mehendi (henna), a few days later mehendi scraps appear (may be the reason is due to chemical mehendi). They separate from skin with time by themselves. It is very difficult to Remove them by ourselves.

Does those scraps effect our ablution?

If we perform ablution will it be valid?

Comment: the basic thing which is must is, the water must penetrate down do to your skin, that is those mehendi scraps must be permeable. And anyways, try natural mehendi made of leaves than that....

Answer (score 2):

Generally, henna is not counted as an obstacle material. In other word it doesn’t prevent conveying the water to the hands (palms) and nails, although you can see its colour... Then it could be OK and permissible to use that. Of course its explanation looks be related to the common (natural) Henna not, artificial…. But in regard to your sentence that said

> It is very difficult to remove them by ourselves

In similar items which could be problem for the Wudu or ablution, you should do your best in order to removing that (as much as you can). Besides, as a constructive helpful point, you should pay heed concerning the sort of the material. Actually as a general Islamic rule (for Wudu and Qusl):

Whatever considers as the obstacle between the skin and water, then it would invalidate the Wudu and Qusl. You’d better to fee the following source if you know Farsi.

---

**Sources:**

- [talabehpasokhgoo.parsiblog.com](http://talabehpasokhgoo.parsiblog.com/Posts/1769/)
- [www.bayynat.ir](http://www.bayynat.ir/index/?state=es&gid=91)